# Struts 2 Anotations for Serverside validations of Objects, Arraylist,Arrays

Tags: validation, struts2, annotations

Is it possible to do server side validations for arrays,Arraylist,Objects using the default annotations provided by Struts2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you need to use the [***Visitor Field Validator***](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/VisitorFieldValidator.html).

Long time ago I've written something about using it (in XML) [***here***](http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/06/struts-2-struts-2-xml-validation.html);

Basically, you write validation rules for ONE object (or "Row"), and you tell the Action to validate that object with Visitor Validator; if you send an array or a list of 100 objects (from the JSP to the Action), each of them will be validated through the visitor validator that is placed (or annotated) in the package where the object is declared, not in the Action package.

Comment: Is it advisable to use annotations for server-side validation for shopping sites..Is there any other way to do global validations rather than hard coding in validate method for each class

Comment: In Struts2 you have three ways: XML Validation (read my post) OR Annotation Validation, AND eventually Validate() method. Then, XML + validate(), or Annotations + validate(), or XML alone or Annotations alone or validate() alone.

Comment: Define "not working", with full details by editing your answer. Visitor Field Validator WORKS, I've used it many ways along with thousands of other people ;) You just need to do it correctly

Comment: i tried this code [@visitorfieldvalidator]..But the validation doesn't occured...when i tried other validations like [@regex],[@RequiredFieldValidator] its working

Comment: [link](http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/05/10/struts-2-validation-using-annotations)

Comment: I am not able to post code corerctly.. Please see the link.. I tried the same way ..But it doesn't helped me

Comment: Dude, it is impossible to tell what you are doing wrong without seeing your code. That article is right, have you followed it step by step ? To correctly format your code in StackOverflow editor, select it and press CTRL+K, or press the code button (`{}`), or indent by FOUR spaces (the outermost part of) your code, with an enter at the top and possibly one at the bottom.