# How to create a generic validation.xml in struts 2 application?

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

For instance, I have a field to enter telephone number and i want it to be validated. I.e. check if the value entered is numeric and check if the entered value is having 10 digits.
I achieved this by creating a `validation.xml`. 
But my question is How can i use the same set of validation rules(the same file) for another field? Is that possible in Struts 2?

Comment: You can create validation for domain objects and use `visitor` validator. See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/visitor-validator.html.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/16131248/1654265 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016661/1654265

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:
Create a new file called validators.xml in WEB-INF/classes and define the new validator.

```
<validator name="newvalidator" class="FQCN"/>
```

Create a class which extends FieldValidatorSupport to implement your own validation logic.

Use the new validator in validation xml files

```
<field-validator type="newvalidator">
```