# How to apply xml validation to dynamically generated fields struts2

Tags: xml, struts2, dynamically-generated, struts-validation

I have a text box on my jsp page as follows:

```
<input id="newHardware_details_0__hardware_type" name="details[0].hardware_type" >
```

I also have an '`add`' button, on click of which I am generating text box dynamically through JavaScript. which have names as follows:

```
details[1].hardware_type
details[2].hardware_type
details[3].hardware_type
.
.
```

How do I validate these text boxes through XML based validations.

**EDIT**

I don't know the syntax to use when dealing with such scenario. For a static field I would write following entry in `ActionClass-validation.xml`:

```
<field name="name">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>You must enter a name</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Comment: You can use Struts2 validation farmework What is the issue?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/visitor-validator.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM i got some idea. but i am not sure how to use it in my case. can you please guide me about it?

Comment: Create validator for your object and use visitor validator on your list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016661/1654265

Comment: ok, i can see how to get field name to validate  as 'details.hardware_type'. but how do i get 'details[0].hardware_type', 'details[1].hardware_type' to validate?

Comment: Have you read the "article" linked in that answer ? BTW you need to specify that "details" is visitor, and in details-validation.xml adding your validation for "hardware_type" and other stuff

Comment: Thanks all! very nicely written article @AndreaLigios

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 2 Anotations for Serverside validations of Objects, Arraylist,Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011949/struts-2-anotations-for-serverside-validations-of-objects-arraylist-arrays)